# Use jsPDF to add a rounded image

Tags: javascript, image, jspdf

I am adding an image to my PDF document using the [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) library:

```
loadImageFromURL(URL, function (image) {
    document.circle(20, 20, 10, 'S');
    document.addImage(image, 'JPEG', 20, 20);
});

function loadImageFromURL(URL, callback) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = URL;

    image.onload = function () {
        callback(image);
    };
}
```

The problem is that I want to fit the image in the circle that I create before adding the image. How can I transform my image to crop into a circle and fit it in my previous circle?

I have tried to:

```
image.style.borderRadius = "50%";
```

But this didn't take any effect. How can I crop my image into a circle?

---

**EDIT:**

After some research I have found out that jsPDF doesn't accept styles. I have also found that jsPDF has a "clip" function, but I am not sure how to use it. Could I somehow add my image and then clip it with a circle?

Answer (score -2):

I have a hack to get a rounded image in jspdf library by simply using an image and circle.

```
    //First I Created Background from Rectangle with some color
    doc.setFillColor(94,101,121);
    doc.setDrawColor(94,101,121); 
    doc.rect(0, 0,width, 115, 'FD');
    
    //Secondly I take a picture in square format
    doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 84, 9, 52, 52,3,3);
    doc.setLineWidth(0);
    doc.setDrawColor(0)
    doc.setFillColor(255, 255, 255)
    
    //Third,I Created a circle and increased the line width until 
    it covers all the corners of image in circuralar format   
    doc.setLineWidth(15)
    doc.setDrawColor(94,101,121); 
    doc.setFillColor(255, 0, 0)
    doc.circle(110, 35, 33, 'Fd')
```

First , Try this code in https://parall.ax/products/jspdf then implement the idea according to your need.